# How to integrate firebse list ui with algolia search capabilities

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui, algolia

My question is how can i filter firebase data with algolia using the firebase list or recyclerview ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [InstantSearch Android](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android/), Algolia's library for building search interfaces in Android apps. Its [`Hits` widget](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android/widgets.html#hits) is based on a `RecyclerView` and is made to display your search hits.

Have a look at the [Getting Started Guide](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android/getting-started.html), or at one of the [example applications](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples) like this Media example:

[image: media example]

Answer (score 0):

The significant solution is to store/index `Firebase` data in the Algolia db using [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).
Whatever you use for the search engines including `ElasticSearch` or `Algolia` the principal is the same.
After the indexing the `Firebase` data with `Algolia`, you can use [Algolia Android Client SDK](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/android/getting-started/).

Comment: Thank you but i have already done that, i wanted to integrate them with the firebase list adapter ui or a custom adapter which will filter out the data, is there a way?

Comment: In a word, `Algolia` is independent from `Firebase`, so you need to write a custom adapter using `Algolia Android Client SDK `.

Comment: Yes, the answer that i am looking for is to show me how because i couldn't find the best code